# How to translate engagement

Tags: traducción

In the context of the game industry, engagement is the voluntary act of a person to participate in an experience.

How should I translate this word into Spanish? The Spanish [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement) page for engagement says that this word can be used in Spanish, but is it correct to use it in scientific research?

The following translations don't mean the same as engagement to a game:

- `compromiso`, `obligación`, `contrato`: it's not an obligatory activity; it's an action that a person wants to perform.
- `cita`: it's not a relationship between two people; it's an activity between a person and a computer.

An example:

> Through a consistent and insightful approach to teaching, dynamic
>   learning will be assured within this very important aspect of engaging
>   the nursing student within the learning process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an added note, although **involucrarse** is used, as was pointed out before, another option is **implicarse**:

> El grado de implicación de las personas en los objetivos de la empresa.

Answer (score 6):

I have understood that **enganchamiento** (*hook*) is said, but these neologisms never have a very long life.

In my work environment **involucramiento** (*involvement*) is used, and it seems an acceptable translation.

Comment: I believe _involucrar_ works better in the example given by the OP _"...dentro de este importante aspecto de involucrar al estudiante de enfermería en el proceso de aprendizaje"_

Answer (score 4):

Previously, *engagement* was used mostly in the sense of "commitment", for example with a cause, movement, mission, etc.  It could be translated as "compromiso," just as one would do for a couple who is engaged to be married.

Currently we see this word more and more in the sense of

> Engage: To attract and hold the attention of; engross: *a hobby that engaged her for hours at a time.* ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/engage))

For this meaning, which I believe is what you were asking about, I like to use a  down-to-earth term that gets past the buzz word and down to what's really going on when someone is *engaged* in learning or playing a game:

**despertar / mantener el interés**

For the noun *engagement* I would make some adjustments so as to use the verb form, or perhaps use *nivel de interés* (level of interest).  (In fact, "level" or "levels" is often part of the original sentence in English.)

Examples of usage:

(1) This game gets a high level of engagement.

> Este juego logra mantener el interés.

(2) Dynamic learning is an important aspect of engaging the nursing student.

> El aprendizaje dinámico es un aspecto importante de despertar y mantener el interés del estudiante de enfermería.

(Hopefully the rest of the article would have made clear what was meant by "dynamic learning" -- which I took to mean things like hands-on activities, interactive lecture style, etc.)

(3) When engagement is high, teaching is effective.

> Con altos niveles de interés, la enseñanza es eficaz.

Answer (score 2):

To engage with a game:
*Vincularse*, *Involucrarse*.

However in LatinAmerica at the app and game development slang,  currently the word *engagement* is vastly and properly used,  and indeed is *the word* that defines the actual and material engagement of a user with an app or game.  Here an anglicism is used to define the engagement.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a point. On military terminology the expression *rules of engagement* which is used to define the different commitments that must be fullfilled during combat is translated into spanish as *reglas de compromiso*

I prefer the proposed *involucrarse*, however it seems that *compromiso* is also accepted and used

Answer (score 1):

Engagement is **not** *compromiso*, not how you mean it.

The act of engaging has several different meanings; enter into a commitment, enter into combat (which is where rules of engagement comes from, which certainly does not translate as "reglas de compromiso"), hold the attention of someone - and, this latter one is the one you want.

*An* engagement is **not** *engagement*. There is no direct translation to Spanish, which is why we native Spanish speakers use engagement in the tech industry.

Whenever you need to keep users *engaged* with your app to sustain, say, a subscription or ad revenue based business, you just say engagement.

You're not keeping them involucrados (you can be involved in something against your will), comprometidos (you commited to something in the past and that's a state you're now in), interesados (being interested in something is a passive activity)... Engagement is proactive and ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reactivar - reengagement
2. Activo - engaged

El porcentaje de actividad del usuario aumenta una vez hace click.

Actividad can mean engaged when put into the right context...

Comment: Esto fue resuelto de mejor manera en 2015 y esta respuesta no aporta nada nuevo