# ¿Posibles traducciones para "Challenger" en español?

Tags: traducción

Hoy me encontré con la frase "[Engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12030/5481) and teach as a challenger", que podría traducirse como

> Involucra y enseña con un desafío
>
> Involucra y enseña como una persona que desafía

Evidentemente las connotaciones de `challenger` en este caso son positivas. Es un desafío no hostil que pretende sacar lo mejor de cada uno. Sin embargo el término "challenger" en sí resulta bastante difícil de traducir. ¿Debería ser "aquel que desafía"? ¿Un "desafiante"? He de recalcar también que la traducción de "con un desafío" me gusta menos, porque un *challenger* no necesariamente propone un único reto.

Desafío (o desafíar) [según el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CNE8fk7) tiene el significado de "Rivalidad, competencia", cuyas connotaciones no cuadran con el significado de la frase original. ¿Es posible traducir `challenger` al español manteniendo las connotaciones positivas de "motivar a alguien a ir más allá de su zona de confort o límites y probarse a sí mismo"?

Comment: En estos casos, puede ser útil cambiar el orden de las palabras para obtener un significado similar, por ejemplo: "Estimula a los demás involucrándolos y enseñándoles".

Comment: Podrías dar más contexto? *Challenger* puede ser una persona o una idea más abstracta, y en ambos casos, es bastante polisémico

Answer (score 3):

Entre las definiciones de *reto* y *desafío* hay acepciones tanto "buenas" como "malas", lo cual no implica que cuando se usen esas palabras tengan que tener ambos sentidos. La verdad es que traducir *challenger* como *desafiador* o *retador* no me suena demasiado bien, pero como ya han propuesto, se puede jugar con el lenguaje para escribir la frase de estas otras formas:

> Involucra y enseña mediante retos.
>   Involucra y enseña proponiendo retos.
>   Involucra y enseña planteando retos.

Concretamente, hay una acepción de *[reto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WHyT2Ax)* que me encanta y cuadra mucho con lo que buscas:

> 5. m. Objetivo o empeño difícil de llevar a cabo, y que constituye por ello un estímulo y un desafío para quien lo afronta.

Si eres una persona que propone retos, eres un *[retador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WFvVj5t)* ("que reta"), o sea un *challenger*.

Answer (score 0):

Las ideas de @Charlie inspiraron esta traducción:

> Enseñar por medio de actividades estimulantes y retadoras

Notas:

- La frase será de mayor utilidad y flexibilidad si se plantea en forma infinitiva.
- La idea básica tiene que ver con la enseñanza, por lo que empiezo con *enseñar*.
- Se exhorta el oyente a utilizar ciertas técnicas pedagógicas.
- Se necesita una consigna que se oiga natural.  Para ello funcionan bien estas formas: *(Verbo) por medio de* o *(Verbo) a través de*.
- "To engage", a mi aviso, quiere decir *estimular el interés del estudiante.*  Material que es *engaging* es lo menos *seco* posible.
- Para lograr un alto nivel de *engagement*, hay que usar un método *activo*.  De ahí, las *actividades*.
- Quedaría más fiel a las palabras originales "actividades estimulantes y retos" pero una estructura paralela será más pegadiza.
- "Challenger" no se debe traducir muy precisamente, con sustantivo, porque se oye raro en inglés y más raro aún en español.
- El tono de la frase original es publicitario, así que lograr una frase melíflua es más importante que mantener el orden original de palabras.

See also https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26143/9385.