# ¿Es acertada la traducción del título de la película/cómic "Escuadrón suicida"?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, españa

Hace relativamente poco tiempo se estrenó en cines la película *Suicide Squad*, basada en el cómic homónimo, cuyo título en España vino a ser *Escuadrón suicida*. Y la verdad es que si lo pienso, creo que la elección de la palabra "escuadrón" se pudo deber a que aquí suena mejor que otras como *equipo*, *pelotón*, *cuadrilla* o *escuadra*.

Según el Merriam-Webster, la palabra *squad* [significa](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squad):

> 1. a small organized group of military personnel; especially :  a tactical unit that can be easily directed in the field
> 2. a small group engaged in a common effort or occupation

Dejando de lado la palabra *equipo*, que me parece más genérica, pongo a continuación [las definiciones más relevantes del resto de opciones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPu4JmR%7CBQ5Txes%7CGLLWtxS%7CGLQPf9S):

> **Pelotón**
>
> 4. m. *Mil.* Pequeña unidad de infantería que forma parte normalmente de una sección y suele estar a las órdenes de un sargento o de un cabo.
>
> **Cuadrilla**
>
> 1. f. Grupo de personas reunidas para el desempeño de algunos oficios o para ciertos fines.
>
> **Escuadra**
>
> 6. f. *Mil.* Unidad menor en las fuerzas militares, constituida por un corto número de soldados a las órdenes de un cabo.
>
> **Escuadrón**
>
> 4. m. *Mil.* Porción de tropa formada en filas según las reglas de la táctica militar.

La segunda definición de *squad* me encaja perfectamente con la definición de *cuadrilla*, aunque entiendo que *Cuadrilla suicida* no habría quedado tan bien como título. Sin embargo, es en la primera definición de *squad* donde me entran las dudas. La primera parte de la definición ("unidad pequeña y organizada de militares") encaja tanto con *pelotón* como con *escuadra*, pero luego añade lo de *especially* y habla de unidades tácticas, con lo que podría entenderse que *escuadrón* también podría ser una traducción válida al hablar de "la táctica militar".

Yo la verdad es que entiendo muy poco de ejércitos, y no sé si realmente *squad* y *escuadrón* son equivalentes. ¿Es *Escuadrón suicida* una buena traducción del título, o se tomaron alguna que otra libertad para tener un título más potente y atrayente?

Comment: Interesante. En parte el cómic "Challengers of Unknown" (traducido al español como "Investigadores de lo desconocido") me motivó también a hacer [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20195/5481), aunque el contexto aquí es bastante diferente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En términos militares, el equivalente a *squad* podría ser *pelotón*; sin embargo, el escuadrón suicida de la película no es una unidad militar al uso y su jefe no es un sargento, como sería el de un pelotón (o una *squad*), sino un coronel. Por tanto, *escuadrón* puede ser una traducción aceptable. En español, la unidad mandada por un coronel es normalmente un regimiento, pero esto no lo es.

Supongo que los traductores se inclinaron por un término que les sonara bien y, de paso, se relacionara fácilmente con el original, pues los lectores de cómics (no olvidemos que la película está basada en un cómic) suelen manejar los títulos originales. En este caso, no me parece que hicieran una mala elección.

Podemos establecer también una analogía con algunas otras construcciones inglesas que también usan la palabra *squad*. Así, *firing squad* es en castellano un *pelotón de fusilamiento*; pero *death squad* equivale a nuestro *escuadrón de la muerte*.

Comment: Bueno, no me refería al hecho de respetar la traducción del cómic. Podemos si quieres trasladar la pregunta a los que tradujeron el cómic, para ver si fueron ellos los que hicieron una buena traducción o no. Con respecto a que sea un coronel (y no un sargento o cabo) el que manda la unidad, ¿es relevante realmente?

Comment: En efecto, hablaba de la traducción del cómic; ahí es donde estaba justificando el uso de una palabra parecida. En cuanto a quién manda la unidad, sí es relevante. Pretendía justificar con esto que el grupo de la película (y el cómic) no se corresponde realmente con la unidad militar llamada *squad*, por lo que no hay por qué traducir la palabra con el nombre de la unidad correspondiente. Aparte de que esa correspondencia no es exacta, pues en inglés también tienen la palabra *platoon* para pelotón y la escuadra española es distinta de la *squad* estadounidense.

Comment: Por aclarar: una *squad* es un grupo pequeño, formado por siete u ocho militares de tropa mandados por un sargento. El tamaño es adecuado, pero ni los miembros son tropa ni quien los manda es un sargento; por tanto, no creo que sea necesaria una traducción literal.

Comment: The British army does not use squad in this formal sense, we call it a section, so for us it has an informal feel. How do you translate similar squads like death squad, firing squad? That might give a clue as to what the "best" translation might be.

Comment: @mdewey *Firing squad* would be *pelotón de fusilamiento*, but the most usual name for a *death squad* is *escuadrón de la muerte*.

Comment: So maybe that explains the original if death squad is _escuadrón_ perhaps suicide squad is by analogy _escuadrón_. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestion, @mdewey. I'll add that to my answer.